# undefined reference to something for what I have a library for

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

When compiling my school project written in C I get following errors:

```
/tmp/ccFDQk9j.o: In function `main':
proj2.c:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `sem_open' (several times)
proj2.c:(.text+0x35a): undefined reference to `sem_post' (several times)
proj2.c:(.text+0x381): undefined reference to `sem_wait' (several times)
proj2.c:(.text+0x6ec): undefined reference to `sem_close' (several times)
proj2.c:(.text+0xda6): undefined reference to `sem_unlink' (several times)
```

My libraries are:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>           
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>       
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <time.h>
```

And I am compiling using:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic proj2.c -o ext
```

Any ideas?

(Also I am ashamed to admit I put everything into one main. Yeah. Please don't stone me.)

EDIT:
So I adjusted my compilation settings to:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pthread proj2.c -o ext
```

And the amount of complaints has been reduced to these only two:

```
/tmp/cc51XZFK.o: In function `main':
proj2.c:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `shm_open'
proj2.c:(.text+0xdf9): undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

EDIT 2.0:
Same error mistake for

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -lrt -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pthread proj2.c -o ext
```

EDIT 3.0:
Successfully compiled. Thank you Paul Griffiths and Joachim Isaksson.

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic proj2.c -pthread  -lrt -o ext
```

Comment: I _think_ you need to link with `-pthread`...?

Comment: Header files and libraries are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `sem_*` functions, [link with `-pthread`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open).

For `shm_*` functions, [link with `-lrt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open).

Comment: -lrt does nothing for me

Comment: @user3473750 You need to list the libraries you want (`-lrt`) _last_, after the c file. The (gnu) linker is quite picky about the order.

Comment: Put your libraries at the end of the command line when you invoke `gcc`, not at the beginning. The order matters.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to link with a library where those `sem_*` methods are.

```
-lpthread
```

Comment: It helped, sort of. Do you have any idea how to get rid of the last two warnings?